# $psprintf functionality from home-grown logger?

Tags: system-verilog

Has anyone come up with a smart way to support `$psprinf` (or `$sformat`) like functionality for your own loggers?

I.e I would like to change my lines from:

```
  log.info($psprintf(" The burst took %0d cycles as expected", cycle_count));
```

to:

```
  log.info(" The burst took %0d cycles as expected", cycle_count);
```

It's mostly a cosmetic goal but adding 10 character to each print line get tedious.

Clever ideas welcomed!

**update**: Note! The main issue is to mimic `$psprintf`'s ability to take in multiple (not exact number of) arguments. I don't think it's supported by the language but I've been away for a couple of years so perhaps something clever has popped up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemVerilog does not support functions or tasks with variable numbers of arguments, but you could use a macro with the maximum number of arguments you expect

```
// must have between 1 and 5 arguments
`define LOG(a1,a2="",a3="",a4="",a5="") log.info($psprintf(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5))

`LOG(" The burst took %0d cycles as expected", cycle_count);
```

If you don't know how many arguments to expect, you will have to pass parenthesis as part of the argument.

```
`define LOG(arg) log.info($psprintf arg )
`LOG((" The burst took %0d cycles as expected", cycle_count));
```

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, I was going down the same path of maximum number of args but was hoping for something better. I had not considered the extra parentheses idea. Both are a little kluge-y but will work. Need to think about if I want to add this or not. Thank you